# Designing a full wave bridge rectifier

Tags: rectifier, bridge

I am making a bridge rectifier using 1n4001 diode and a step down transformer 0-12 my question is:
a) What value of smoothing/filter capacitor should i use?
b) I tried two different capacitor one of 1000uf and other of 100uf capacitor in parallel of the output of bridge rectifier.When i measured the voltage across the capacitor my DMM was showing 19 volts(with both capacitor).My question is why it is showing 19 volts? and when i removed the capacitor DMM was reporting 12 volts?

Comment: First, please provide your output current and voltage ripple requirements.

Comment: Have you read: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html ? If not, do so now.

Comment: Two supplies of 12V and 5V and current 500mA

Comment: “step down transformer 0-12” VTC as unclear.

Comment: Didn't we do this like 2 days ago.. see [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/358285/139766)

Answer (score 4):

When you smooth the output of a full wave rectifier the capacitor gets charged to the peak voltage from the secondary. Given that a 12 volt RMS sinewave has a peak voltage of 17 volts this covers most of the story of what you see.

In an unloaded transformer, the secondary AC voltage may be anything up to 20% higher. This means the peak could be 20.4 volts. A couple of diode drops in your bridge can easily reduce this to about 19 volts.

[image]

The image above shows the unsmoothed output from the rectifier i.e. when not using an output capacitor. The smoothed output peaks close to the maximum AC voltage and has ripple due to current flowing through the resistor R. If R was open circuit, there would be no ripple and the peak voltage would coincide with the peak of the secondary voltage minus a couple of diode drops (1 volt to 1.5 volt typically).

Picture taken from [here](http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Electronics/Semiconductors/text/Rectification_/index.html).

Comment: Actually i want 2 supplies one is of 12V and other is of 5V.Giving 19V to 7812 voltage regulator is fine but is it fine to give 19V to 7805 voltage regulator to get 5V DC?

Comment: The regulator will get quite hot if you are drawing (say) 0.5 amps from it. That current passes through the regulator output transistor and also drops 14 volts. Thus the regulator power dissipated is 7 watts (V x I). I'd use a switching regulator but this increases cost. However, if the device is on 24:7 then the yearly heat bill just for the regulator will be several dollars so you must decide!

Comment: from 7812 voltage regulator i need 500mA but not with 7805 one.No it will not run 24:7.

Answer (score 0):

For a bridge rectifier, the output should be theoretically 24V but in this case, you are getting a pretty fine output of 19v(losses in practical applications tend to diminish the voltage). The most important thing you should look upon is the rating of the capacitor voltage rather than the farad. If you are using 12-0-12 transformer, the filter capacitor should be of 25v or more. Hope this will help otherwise show the circuit you have made. I will help you out.

Comment: How do you calculate that the output is theoretically 24 volts? Why do you think the question is about a 12-0-12 transformer when it clearly states 0-12?

Comment: Would not it act as a simple half wave rectifier rather than a bridge rectifier if he uses only 12-0 of the transformer?

Comment: It's quite common to refer to a single secondary as 0-12 and a split secondary as 12-0-12 but please don't mix them up.

Comment: I am using 0-12 V transformer not a center tapped one 12-0-12 that is why i am making full wave bridge rectifer.